# Securing access to JQuery autocomplete helper

Tags: php, jquery, security, jquery-autocomplete

I've recently [setup an autocomplete on an input field with JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete). I set its source to be a publically accessible PHP page on my server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#q").autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        delay: 500,
        autoFocus: true,
        source: "ac.php"
    });
});
```

ac.php polls a search service running on the server after sanitizing input it receives.

What I want to know is if there are any ways to force access to ac.php only via the autocomplete form? I was thinking checking referrers but that can be bypassed with tools like tamperdata.

Do I even need to worry about leaving the helper publicly accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. Any ajax request in fact is an ordinary HTTP request that can be forged.

> Do I even need to worry about leaving the helper publicly accessible?

No you don't. Treat it as any other resource (page) you have on your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm probably just too paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

not without some form of authentication, perhaps oauth, digest etc.. personally I wouldn't bother.
You could use keys generated every 5 mins on the server and send them as request variables, then try to match them but again this would still allow short term access and cause more issues than it would solve.

Comment: "You could use keys generated every 5 mins on the server and send them as request variables" --- so if a person went on 6 minutes coffee break the whole site should break and refreshing the page should be required?

Comment: yup... and a bunch of other annoyances

Comment: basically, if its public it's public... :-) This is why twitter, google etc use oauth for their apis

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to worry or not depends on your circumstances. One way to know if request came from Ajax call is to check `X-Requested-With` header in your PHP script. It will be set by jQuery to `XMLHttpRequest`. Look here for example: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: The question was: "if there are any ways to force access to ac.php only via the autocomplete form?", not "How to determine if request is XHR one"

Comment: it could still be easily spoofed

Comment: ps.. I'm loving this on your blog: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_ig3wnao3bQ/T_OwxmBylYI/AAAAAAAAAbY/bJ6lJEnIxuQ/s1600/Melbourne_earthquake_2012.jpg

Comment: @Alex: That is how we deal with earthquakes down under :-D (Sorry for off-topic).